# R Dataframe: Get column 2 where column 1 value = x?

Tags: r, dataframe

Basic question but I'm a beginner sorry :-) And I still struggle with all these different data types etc. So I have a table with different variable names in column 1. In column 2 These variables have certain values. I want to extract now the value for a certain variable.

```
VarNames<-read.table(paste("O:/Daten/RatsDaten/CodesandDescription/VarNamesDir.asc"), sep="", skip=0,header=FALSE)
```

And the table Looks somehow like this

```
Test1      5
Test2      7
Test3      1
```

So how do I Access these Test variable values with their names? VarNames["Test1",2] didn't work..neither did any other option I've tried. Are there better data type options for this or how would I do it with a comfortable data frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have one of this 2 situations , either

Testxx are rownames of VarNames, you can test this using rownames(VarNames), and in this case you should do :

```
    VarNames["Test1",1]
```

Or Testxx are components of a column, and you should do something like this :

```
    VarNames[VarNames$v =='Test1',2]
```

For the first option :

```
m <- matrix(1:3,ncol=1,dimnames=list(paste0('Test',1:3),NULL))
m['Test1',]
Test1 
    1
```

for the second option

```
m1 <- data.frame(v=paste0('Test',1:3),b=1:3)
m1[m1$v=='Test1',]
      v b
1 Test1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As your example is not reproducible, it is unclear whether the first column denotes row names or a variable with values TestX.

In case it is a variable, your table actually looks like this:

```
V1         V2
Test1      5
Test2      7
Test3      1
```

So you can get value of `Test2` by calling `VarNames[VarNames$V1 == "Test2",]` for the whole row or `VarNames[VarNames$V1 == "Test2",2]` for the value only. You specify 2 since it is the second column.

If the first column denotes row names, the call is `VarNames["Test2",]` for the whole row, or as @agstudy answered, `VarNames["Test2",1]` for the value alone. You specify 1 since it is the first column provided `Test2` is a row name, and thus is not contained in a column.

Comment: @agstudy Not enough coffee this morning apparently ;) Fixed, thanks for catching.